# The c function is not working for all files trying to send

Tags: c, file, sockets, ftp, send

I am trying to build an FTP server client. I have written this function to send files but it is not working for all files. Though it is working for some file such as jpg when it comes to ppt or other files it is creating a problem. I am trying to send 100 bytes each time of a file I am working on ubuntu 18.04

previously I tried the library function to send the file over a socket. but that also did not help as well.

```
void sendfiledata(int sockfd, char * filename) {

    FILE * file;
    unsigned long fileLen;
    file = fopen(filename, "rb");

    //Get file length
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    long int loop = fileLen / 100;
    long int remainfile = fileLen % 100;

    buffer = (char * ) malloc(fileLen);

    fread(buffer, fileLen, sizeof(char), file);
    fclose(file);

    send(sockfd, & fileLen, sizeof(int), 0);
    int i = 0;
    char chunk[100];
    for (int j = 0; j < loop; j++) {
        int k = 0;
        while (i < fileLen && k < 100) {
            chunk[k] = buffer[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        send(sockfd, chunk, 100, 0);
    }
    if (remainfile > 0) {
        int k = 0;
        while (i < fileLen && k < remainfile) {
            chunk[k] = buffer[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        send(sockfd, chunk, remainfile, 0);
    }
    memset(filename, '\0', sizeof(filename));
}
```

i want the files to be send fully from one machine to another. but here some files are working but not all.

Comment: your code is overly complicated ... and can you share how big is the file that you are trying to send when it does NOT work?\

Comment: What exactly means "it is creating a problem"? What happens and what do you want to happen?

Comment: Your way to send the length of the file is very suspicious, see my answer

Comment: You must correctly and completely handle the result returned from system calls like send().

Comment: I am trying to send all kinds of file despite of their size.

Comment: It can be either 1kb or 10Mb.

Comment: The files i am trying to send are not going fully. Like i have sent a text file with 280 lines but i the file i received had 169 lines . For jpg files the change is not visible. Last time i tried to sent a ppt file it was all messed up. i have corrected my send() to send file size. i used int there previously. The final result should be i can send any file from server to client fully.

Comment: Sorry , couldn't understand what you meant by handle the result returned from system calls like send()

Comment: Mostly i am trying to send files with in 10 mb. it is working when the files are small such as 100kb to 1 mb.

Comment: @RadowanMahmudRedoy you suppose _send_ always send the expected number of bytes, this may not be the case without being an error, you need to check the return value. I edited my answer, see it